# Linkedin Job Search avoid unrelated jobs

Tags: linkedin-api

How can I avoid linkedin to show unrelated jobs?

I want to search jobs that contain the specific word I'm writing, but the search engine is always showing excesive data.

Even if I write non sense words, I get data:

[image]

Comment: But how will LinkedIn get clicks if they don't return results when there's nothing useful to return?

Comment: haha, yes I know, for now the only way I found is to search on incognito window without logging in.